# Insert another XML element of the same type

Tags: nxml

In nxml-mode, I would like to insert an XML tag that has the same name as the nearest closing tag before point, without having to retype (or complete) the same tag name each time I do it.

Answer (score 1):

This requires the `expand-region` package.

```lisp
(defun repeat-element ()
  "start a new XML element with the same name as the previous XML element"
  (interactive)
  (er/expand-region 1)
  (replace-regexp "</\\([^>]+\\)>" "\\&
<\\1" nil (region-beginning) (region-end) nil)
  (funcall indent-line-function))
```